# I was getting more monkey

Tags: idioms

This is from Good Luck Charlie.

PJ took the baby out to the park. But he brought a wrong baby home. The children were anxious. At this moment, mom called to ask how was it going with the baby. Teddy told her everything was great. After she ended the call, PJ said,

> Not that I'm in the position to criticize, but I was *getting more monkey*.

I guess it's an idiom. But what does it mean? Does it come from monkey on one's back?

Comment: Are you sure the word is **monkey**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little more context would have been helpful here:

> Well, what do we do now? ( cell phone ringing )
>
> Oh no! Hi mom, what up? Yeah, everything's going great. Why wouldn't it be? We're just having a grand old time here with-- Baby.
>
> Yeah, sure you can talk to him. Her her! Talk to mommy. Ooh-ooh ee ahh-ahh.
>
> What do you mean that didn't sound like charlie?
>
> What, do you just think I'm making baby noises into the phone? Mom, that's crazy. All right, bye. Say bye, charlie. Ooh ahh-ahh-ahh.
>
> Not that I'm in the position to criticize, But I was getting more monkey.

A mother is calling on the phone to talk to a baby, but for some reason the baby isn’t there. (I didn’t read the whole episode.) So someone else pretends to be a baby to try to reassure the mother.

“Getting more monkey” means “Your imitation of a baby sounded more like a monkey to me.”